# auto upload image with facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm searching, reading many codes, but my problem is still, I want to upload image on facebook page, but when I run my code, it post on page with my profile, not on page timeline, my code is given below

```
function _Post($Message, $Pic)
{
    require_once ("library/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php");
    $options = (object)array(); // Options
    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = $options->posttopage_appID;
    $config['secret'] = $options->posttopage_appSecret;
    $config['fileUpload'] = true; // optional
    $fb = new Facebook($config);

    $fb->setFileUploadSupport(true);
    $params = array(
        "access_token" => $options->posttopage_access_token,
        "message" => $Message,
        //'aid' => xxxxxx,
        "image" => '@' . $Pic
    );
    try
    {
        $ret = $fb->api('/' . $options->posttopage_PageID . '/photos', 'POST', $params);
         echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
         echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
_Post('Message', '/home/username/public_html/image.png')
```

If I change `photos` with `feed` in api code, I post as page posts, So I to know that how can I upload image on page as we post from facebook web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using page access token and not yours. Try getting access token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer. You can also try api calls and see what will be result

Comment: I generate my access token from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, where can I get page access token ?

Comment: "Get Token" -> "Page Access Tokens"

Answer (score 0):

In order to post "as Page", you have to authorize with the `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permissions and generate/use a Page Token in the API call.

More information about Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

I suggest using an Extended Page Token for auto-publishing to a Page, it is valid forever.

Comment: I have to post/upload image with out browsing this file, I mean with cronjob, So can I get permissions with out login everytime ?

Comment: of course, you just need to use an extended page token, as explained in the links

Comment: add the info to my answer

Comment: Infact I was generating wrong token, I select application, and no page